# Logic error in swapping a peg jump puzzle

Tags: c, logic, swap

Can someone help me with swapping. I think there's a logical error. I know that the source piece and destination are correct so something is up with my if statements. Rules for the game: The game starts off with a pyramid structure full of all '+' except one circle 'o', and you can only move a peg to a circle adjacently(two spots over/diagonally), any piece skipped over will be replaced with a circle as well. So example you could move diagonally two spots over, and the middle jumped over piece would be circled out as well as the original position, but the piece that you are moving to will have its circle replaced with a '+'. The visual image is down below. Furthermore, the variables correspond to letters. Ex: pa is for spot A, pb is for spot B and so forth.

First move is from D to A. Second move is from K to D. I am getting the incorrect output. Spots K, G, and B should be vacant because B was skipped from the first move and G is being skipped this turn. But here I am getting A as vacant even though it just had a '+'. Now A had updated from the first move in the game, but now it's back at a circle. A, or 'pa' should've been updated from the following statement: `*pa = *pd;`

Here is the link to the code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/puab7va8vosftdd/Source.c?dl=0

```
void moveHandler( char source, char destination, char *pa, char *pb, char *pc, char *pd, char *pe, char *pf,
                 char *pg, char *ph, char *pi, char *pj, char *pk, char *pl, char *pm, char *pn, char *po ) {
                     char temp;
                     char middle;

                     if ( (source || destination == 'D') && (destination || source == 'A') ) {
                         temp = *pa;
                         *pa = *pd;
                         *pd = temp;
                     }
                     else if ( (source || destination == 'K') && (destination || source == 'D') ) {
                         temp = *pk;
                         *pk = *pd;
                         *pd = temp;
                     }



                     middle = (char) ((source + destination) / 2);

                    switch( middle ) {
                    case 66:
                            *pb = 'o';
                            break;
                    case 71:
                            *pg = 'o';
                            break;
                    default:
                        break;

                    }
}
```

output image: https://snag.gy/yh2c1M.jpg

Comment: Should `(source || destination == 'D')` be changed to `((source == 'D')  || (destination == 'D'))?  (in all places where you are applying this logical test)

Comment: Oh crap. Let me try that. Thank you

Comment: Well actually I want to run it if source or destination is d AND if source or destination is a, if that makes sense.

Comment: This works, thank you.

Comment: A function with such a large parameter list most times shows a bad interface design. Use self-explanatory names and consider using `struct`s or otherwise reduce the interface.

Comment: the link to the actual code is broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your logical comparisons/tests need to be modified.  The logical operators `&&` and `||` each need to be applied to the value being compared to.  For example, the way it is written, `source` is being OR'ed to `destination`, then the results of that are being tested for equality with the `char` 'D'.  I believe what you probably intended is shown below.

Change:

```
if ( (source || destination == 'D') && (destination || source == 'A') ) {
                         temp = *pa;
                         *pa = *pd;
                         *pd = temp;
                     }
                     else if ( (source || destination == 'K') && (destination || source == 'D') ) {
                         temp = *pk;
                         *pk = *pd;
                         *pd = temp;
                     }
```

To:  ( *EDIT* - corrected first statement, replaced D with A)

```
if ( ((source =='D') || (destination == 'D')) && ((source =='A') || (destination == 'A')) ) {
                                                                                    ^^^
                         temp = *pa;
                         *pa = *pd;
                         *pd = temp;
                     }
                     else if (( (source == 'K') || (destination == 'K')) && ((destination == 'D') || (source == 'D')) ) {
                         temp = *pk;
                         *pk = *pd;
                         *pd = temp;
                     }
```

And, although this may be what you *intended*, it may not be what is necessary to solve the problem.  In the first `if(...)` statement, regardless of whether `A` or `D` are the `destination` or the `source`, data is copied from `A` to `D`. In that form, the actual intent of the code is not clear, and possibly will not do what is needed.

Create syntax that provides clarity of intention.

For example, consider that in your code snippet, you clearly have identified 3 possible sources and 3 possible destinations:

[image]

Although the following pseudo code suggestion is not as terse as your original syntax (often a desired feature) it is more explicit, shows clear intent and covers all possible source/destination transactions:

```
if(     (source == ‘A’)&&(destination == ‘D’)){//copy A to D}
else if((source == ‘A’)&&(destination == ‘K’)){//copy A to K}
else if((source == ‘D’)&&(destination == ‘A’)){//copy D to A}
else if((source == ‘D’)&&(destination == ‘K’)){//copy D to K}
else if((source == ‘K’)&&(destination == ‘A’)){//copy K to A}
else if((source == ‘K’)&&(destination == ‘D’)){//copy K to D}
```

Comment: this answer says: if (source is D or source is A ) and destination is D.   or if ( source is K and (destination is K or destination is D)    Are you sure that is what you want?